# How can I get an hit without a exact match with es 2.X? (Python elasticsearch)

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a problem with elasticsearch. There is an item ("'title': 'Using Python with Elasticsearch'") in the index. I can get the returned result only I searh the exact query. However, when I searh the "'title': 'Using Python with'", the code can hit nothing.
The es version is :                                               {u'cluster_name': u'elasticsearch', u'tagline': u'You Know, for Search', u'version': {u'lucene_version': u'5.4.1', u'build_hash': u'd045fc29d1932bce18b2e65ab8b297fbf6cd41a1', u'number': u'2.2.1', u'build_timestamp': u'2016-03-09T09:38:54Z', u'build_snapshot': False}, u'name': u'Lorelei Travis'}
If I am right, it should be es 2.2.1. The code is attached. So, how can I get the hit, when I search with the query like "Using Python with", without an exact match query.   Thanks!

```
INDEX_NAME = 'test_11'
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
print es.info()

request_body = {  
      "mappings":{  
        "post":{  
          "properties":{  
            "title":{  
              "type":"string",
              "index":"analyzed"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }

if es.indices.exists(INDEX_NAME):
    res = es.indices.delete(index = INDEX_NAME)
    print(" response: '%s'" % (res))

res = es.indices.create(index = INDEX_NAME, body=request_body)
print res

es.index(index=INDEX_NAME, doc_type='post', id=1, body={
  'title': 'Using Python with Elasticsearch'
  }
)

es.indices.refresh(index=INDEX_NAME)

res = es.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body={'query': {'match': {'title': 'Using Python with Elasticsearch'}}})
#res = es.search(index=INDEX_NAME, body ={"query":{"match":{"title":"Using Python with"}}})

print '\n'
res = es.indices.get(index=INDEX_NAME)
print res
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [prefix](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) query? If you want something fancier, consider [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-regexp-query.html) query or [fuzzy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html) query.

EDIT: Correct me if I am wrong: you want `Using Python with` to match all results like `Using Python with Elasticsearch`, `Using Python with Lucene`? Then a mapping like:

```
request_body = {  
  "mappings":{  
    "post":{  
      "properties":{  
        "title":{  
          "type":"string",
          "index":"not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and then a query like:

```
{
    "query": {
        "prefix": {
            "title": "Using Python with"
        }
    }
}
```

Should return all the relevant documents.
Note I changed the `index` field to `not_analyzed`.

More [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-matching.html).

EDIT 2:
If you want to match all documents that contain the exact query anywhere in the target field, not just as a prefix, use a [regexp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) query as suggested initially. Then

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "name": "Using Python with*"
        }
    }
}
```

will work like a prefix query and match both `Using Python with Elasticsearch` as well as `Using Python with Lucene`, but

```
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard": {
            "name": "*Python with Elasticsearch"
        }
    }
}
```

will match `Using Python with Elasticsearch` only. It will not match `Using Python with elasticsearch` but you said you wanted *exact* phrase match.

Comment: I know fuzzy query can achieve this function. But I want achieve full-text search. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks! It works! But I want to achieve full-text search. With query "Python with Elasticsearch", it can hit nothing.

Comment: Ok, then you need a regexp query, I added an example. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  I mainly have a problem for full-text search. For this official tutorial, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/match-query.html                                                                                                      My experiment results is "{"took":1,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
"    It seems that the full-text search donot work! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the `wildcard` query I suggested in the latest edit to my answer?!